# distributed cluster questions about performance

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm using 6 servers to make a cluster and they are all disk nodes. I use rabbitmq for collecting log file for our website. Now at the peak hour, the publish rate is about 30k message per second. There are 2 main consumers(hdfs and elasticsearch) and each one need to handle all message, so the delivery rate hit about 60k per second.

In my scenario, a single server can hold 10k delivery rate and I use 6 node to load balance the pressure. My solution is that I created 2 queues on each node. Each message is with a random routing-key(something like message.0, message.1, etc) to distribute the pressure to every node.

What confused me is:

All message send to one node. Should I use a HA Proxy to load balance this publish pressure?

1. Is there any performance difference between Durable Queues and Transient Queues?
2. Is there any performance difference between Memory Node and Disk Node? What I know is the difference between memory node and disk node is only about the meta data such as queue configuration.
3. How can I imrove the performance in publish and delivery codes? I've researched and I know several methods:

   - disable the confirm mechanism(in publish codes?)
   - enable HiPE(I've done that and it helped a lot)
4. For example, input is 1w mps(message per second), there are two consumers to consume all message. Then the output is 2w mps. If my server can handle 1w mps, I need two server to handle the 2w-mps-pressure. Now a new consumer need to consume all message, too. As a result, output hits 3w mps, so I need another one more server. For a conclusion, one more consumer for all message, one more server?

Comment: have you had a look at http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/04/17/rabbitmq-performance-measurements-part-1/ and http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/04/25/rabbitmq-performance-measurements-part-2/

Comment: in question 3 did you mean import or did you mean improve?

Comment: oh yes, I wanted to type 'improve'

Answer (score 0):

> "All message send to one node. Should I use a HA Proxy to load balance this publish pressure?"

[This](http://insidethecpu.com/2014/11/17/load-balancing-a-rabbitmq-cluster/) article outlines a number of designs aimed at distributing load in RabbitMQ.

> "Is there any performance difference between Durable Queues and Transient Queues?"

Yes, Durable Queues are backed up to disk so that they can be reinstated on server-restart, for example. This adds a nominal overhead, though the actual process occurs asynchronously.

> "Is there any performance difference between Memory Node and Disk Node?"

Not that I'm aware of, but that would depend on the machine itself.

> "How can I imrove the performance in publish and delivery codes?"

Try [this](http://insidethecpu.com/2014/11/11/rabbitmq-qos-vs-competing-consumers/) out.